Evaluate $∬ydxdy$ where R is the region bounded by parabola $x^2=y$ and $x+y=2$.
I created a rough sketch(image provided) which involved a parabola and a straight line. 
Mow when I'm trying to integrate my logic that I use these equations to find a common point (point of intersection rather) and I substitute the value of $x^2$ in the equation $x+y=2$ after which I'm stuck because I can solve for $x$ and get $x$'s limits but how do I get $y$'s limits?

The intersection points are $(-2,4)$ and $(1,1)$. So, $x$ can go from $-2$ to $1$. Besides (look at your picture), for each $x\in[-2,1]$, $y$ can go for $x^2$ to $2-x$. Therefore, you should compute$$\int_{-2}^1\int_{x^2}^{2-x}y\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx.$$

thank you so much! i have a follow up question , if i were to do it on pen - paper how would i get the intersection points

@user17872805 $x^2+x=2\implies x=1\ \text{or}\ x=-2$ and then use $x^2=y$ to get corresponding $y$'s.
